# Ordered Unique Combinations

Tags: c#, arrays, combinations

I have the following class:

```
internal class Course
{
    public int CourseCode { get; set; }
    public string DeptCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the following code is the 2 dimensional array I have:

```
Course[][] courses = new Course[3][];
courses[0] = new Course[] {
   new Course() { CourseCode = 100, DeptCode = "EGR", Name = "EGR A" },
   new Course() { CourseCode = 100, DeptCode = "EGR", Name = "EGR B" }
};

courses[1] = new Course[] {
   new Course() { CourseCode = 200, DeptCode = "EN", Name = "EN A" }
};

courses[2] = new Course[] {
   new Course() { CourseCode = 300, DeptCode = "PHY", Name = "PHY A" }
};
```

What I want to do is get the different combinations that each item in a group could do with the other groups; for example with the previous code, the results would be:

```
1. EGR A - EN A - PHY A
2. EGR B - EN A - PHY A
```

Answers:
To get the number of combinations possible, we can use [Rule of Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), in the above case, the possible combinations will be (2 * 1 * 1) = 2 which is indeed the 2 combinations I wrote above.

LordTakkera has given the perfect answer, thank you so much!

Comment: I am sorry if I made it look like I want people to write code for me. My first attempt was that I wrote a code in which I had an array Course[] that all the possible courses without grouping. I then got all the possible combinations, in that case was n was 7 and k was 3.
I then filtered all the results to take off duplicates which were included in one group, to not allow same category courses in the same array.

This was a really time consuming process though, so I tried finding another way to do it, which was the one listed above. I tried many for loops, but was not able to get it to work. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < courses[0].Length; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < courses[1].Length; i++)
   {
     for (int k = 0; k < courses[2].Length; i++)
     {
         //Do whatever you need with the combo, accessed like:
         //courses[0][i], courses[1][j], courses[2][k]
     }
   }
}
```

Of course, this solution gets really messy the more nesting you need. If you need to go any deeper, I would use some kind of recursive function to traverse the collection and generate the combinations.

It would be something like:

```
class CombinationHelper
{
    public List<List<Course>> GetAllCombinations(Course[][] courses)
    {
            return GetCourseCombination(courses, 0);
    }

    public List<List<Course>> GetCourseCombination(Course[][] courses, int myIndex)
    {
        List<List<Course>> combos = new List<List<Course>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < courses[myIndex].Length; i++)
        {
            if (myIndex + 1 < courses.GetLength(0))
            {
               foreach (List<Course> combo in GetCourseCombination(courses, myIndex + 1))
               {
                  combo.Add(courses[myIndex][i]);
                  combos.Add(combo);
               }
            }
            else
            {
               List<Course> newCombination = new List<Course>() { courses[myIndex][i] };
               combos.Add(newCombination);
            }
        }
        return combos;
    }
}
```

I tested this (substituting "int" for "Course" to make verification easier) and it produced all 8 combinations (though not in order, recursion tends to do that. If I come up with the ordering code, I'll post, but it shouldn't be *too* difficult).

Recursive functions are hard enough for me to come up with, so my explanation won't be very good. Basically, we start by kicking the whole thing off with the "0" index (so that we start from the beginning). Then we iterate over the current array. If we aren't the last array in the "master" array, we recurse into the next sub-array. Otherwise, we create a new combination, add ourselves to it, and return.

As the recursive stack "unwinds" we add the generated combinations to our return list, add ourselves to it, and return again. Eventually the whole thing "unwinds" and you are left with one list of all the combinations.

Again, I'm sure that was a very confusing explanation, but recursive algorithms are (at least for me) inherently confusing. I would be happy to attempt to elaborate on any point you would like.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works, but since the array is dynamic, I cannot depend on writing 2 nested loops. It may be more, or may be less, depending on the user input. Also, you meant j++ and i++ too, right? My end goal is to go through the courses[][] array and find the different unique combinations like what the code you mentioned does, but for any array dimensions. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Yes, i meant j++ and k++. I will post an example of the recursive form in a little bit, that is probably the way you want to go.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! Will be waiting for the example :)

Comment: My head has now exploded from figuring out too much recursion :) Check my example and let me know what you think! I apologize in advance for the lack of ordering.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your effort, I really appreciate it! I will test it out as soon as I can, and will let you know :)
Thanks once again!

Comment: Hello, I tried your code. I love the idea, but I get an Index out of bounds exception. I attempted to fix it, the error is because of the for loop, "i < courses[i].Length". If the array length of the subarray is the same as the 2 dimensional array, this code will work; if the subarray is bigger, it will not work and I do not know how to fix it..

Thank you very much for your code, I will post the correction if I figure it out :)

Comment: try changing the line to `i < courses[myIndex].Length`

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the fix

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your second index - the 0 or 1. If you look only at that, you see a binary number from 0 to 7.

Count from 0 to 7, translate it to bits and get the combination pattern you need.

Comment: +1 for invoking bitwise operations, a nested for loop might be a bit simpler though :)

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll leave it for OP. If I were OP, I would go with the binary representation, for practice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :)
Unfortunately I do not know much about bitwise operations yet, so I do not know how to put your idea into practice..
I would appreciate it if you guided me to the right direction :)

Thanks!

Comment: I also just realized that this will have a problem when the index needs to be "2" which it would given the sample data. Not sure how to fix that part while still counting in binary :(. Still a very clever approach!

Comment: Count in the base of 3, or 4, or 17 if needed.